# side pot scenario

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, all-in, side-pots, drawing

What happens if we have 4 players at the table with the following bets

> -player1 10$ - all-in - Cards: 9d, 5h
>
> -player2 50$ - all-in - Cards: 9h, 4h
>
> -player3 100$ not all-in - Cards:2d,Kc
>
> -player4 100$ not all-in - Cards:2h,Jh
>
> Table cards:9s, 3d, 3s, Ac, 2c

During flop, player 4 raises to 100$. player1 and player2 go all-in. Player3 calls the bet.
Player1 and player2 have the same formation rank and kickers, so they should win, but how much?

I assume that player1 takes 10$ from each player, so he wins 40$ /2 because he splits the first position with another player.

What about player2, player3 and player4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 pots
$40 - player1, player2, player3, player4
$120 - player2, player3, player4
$100 - player3, player4

Hand order
1 - Player1 Player2 tie 9933A
2 - Player3 Player4 tie 3322A

Player1 and Player 2 split the $40 pot
Player2 wins the $120 pot
Player3 and Player4 spit the $100 pot

Comment: The cards/hands of each player is written above at the end of each line. Player3 has pair of 2 and pair of 3, with ACE kicker. Player4 has the same as player3.

Comment: Would this assumption be true: the best hand from each side pot wins that pot or splits it with other players from the pot that have the same formation rank

Comment: Yep, if they have equivalent hands and an equal amount of money in the pot, they would split their side pot(s).

Comment: @Frisbee I think that the 3rd pot should have the value 100+100+50+10 - 40-120 = 100$

Comment: @nvg OK?  I assumed the $100 in text on the river was in addition.  I edited the answer.  Yes, pots should total bets.

Comment: That action would typically  not happen on the river.  You might want to just take the rive part out of the question.